# List sorting on nested struct members

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with sorting out a list using an implementation of IComparer.

```
public struct VAL
{
    public int i;
    public string s;
}

public struct INFO
{
    public string name;
    public VAL val;
    public string address;
}

public class ListSorter:IComparer<INFO>
{
    public enum SORT_TYPE{BYNAME, BYVAL,BYADDRESS};
    public int Compare(INFO i1, INFO i2)
        {
        switch(sortType)
        {
            case SORT_TYPE.BYNAME;
                return string.Compare(i1.name, i2.name);
            case SORT_TYPE.BYADDRESS:
                return string.Compare(i1.address, i2.address); 
            case SORT_TYPE.BYVAL:
            {
                ??????
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

The comparison function in the class ListSorter is an example of how I am comparing strings in the given INFO struct. But I don't know how to sort the list based on the VAL struct information members

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would do something like:

```
case SORT_TYPE.BYVAL:
{
    int ret = i1.VAL.i.CompareTo(i2.VAL.i);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }
    return i1.VAL.s.CompareTo(i2.VAL.s);
}
```

You first compare the `i` and if they are equal you compare the `s` (or the opposite, the order must be selected by you).

Comment: +1 for a clear and correct answer. Only thing missing possibly a suggestion to have VAL implement IComparable and hide how it's members are compared/have a separate IComparer<VAL>

Comment: @KAJ He opted for an "external" comparer instead of "internal" comparison, so I didn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `VAL` is supposed to represent, it's nigh-on impossible for us here to come up with a definitive answer to your question.  A naive implementation would choose one field to prioritise over the other - as xanatos has shown in his answer (and the code he's posted there achieves the logic that I include further down).

I.E. Which sub-comparison is most important, is it the `i` or the `s`? Without knowing that here we can cover all but 2 of the combinations of comparisons - with another 2 'tenuous'.

The following almost-table might help you decide, for two `VAL`s: `VAL1` and `VAL2`:

```
VAL1.i == VAL2.i
(and) VAL1.s == VAL2.s => 0
(or)  VAL1.s < VAL2.s => -1
(or)  VAL1.s > VAL2.s => 1
VAL1.i < VAL2.i
(and) VAL1.s == VAL2.s => -1 //(or possibly 0 if i is not important)
(or) VAL1.s < VAL2.s => -1
(or) VAL1.s > VAL2.s => ??? /** WHICH ONE MAKES SENSE TO YOU? **/
VAL1.i > VAL2.i
(and) VAL1.s == VAL2.s => 1 //(or possibly 0 if i is not important)
(or) VAL1.s < VAL2.s => ??? /** WHICH ONE MAKES SENSE TO YOU? **/
(or) VAL1.s > VAL2.s => 1
```